# Can I plug my SD card from Pi Zero W into a Pi 3A+?

Tags: pi-zero-w, pi-3a+

I currently have a fully updated Pi Zero W running octopi, but its hardware is limited, and I would like to upgrade. Can I take the SD Card from the Zero W and use it in the 3A+? Are there any steps I'd need to complete?

Comment: I would advise against a Pi3A+ as it only has 512Mb RAM. Why not get a Pi4 2GB?

Comment: Yes, I always do that, from Rpi 3, 4 to/from RpiZ/W, without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that OctoPi is essentially the Pi OS with OctoPrint installed. The Pi OS will certainly work if you plug it into a different Pi model, so the OctoPi should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with octopi.

Raspbian and Raspberry Pi OS work on all recent Pis without requiring changes.